# Connect to Cassandra cluster deployed on AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I installed Cassandra on EC2 instance on AWS.
I got .pem file and not sure how to connect to this cluster from Spring Boot application that is running locally on my laptop (I am using Java Datastax Driver to access local Cassandra cluster). If anyone experienced in it, could you please at least give a hint where to look for, thanks in advance.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and issues faced if any?

Comment: Well, I am currently trying to use `Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("ec2address").withSSL()`. But not sure how to import .pem key here using `SSLOptions` into `withSSL()` method